# WPF MVVM Button inside Listview Row not working Unless Click Row First

Tags: wpf, mvvm

[image]

I have two buttons inside listview on every row. one is for showing selected item and other is for showing index number. button for showing selected item works fine, but button for showing index number it doesn't work.

When i click the **button (showing index number)** it returns index number zero '0', i mean it doesn't work properly. but when i select the row and then click the button, then it works, i mean it then returns the correct index number.
what i want is **button (showing index number)** should work without selecting row first.

below is xaml code

```
<ListView                       
    Grid.Row="1"
    ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource FileItemStyle}"
    ItemsSource="{Binding CollViewSourceBarCode.View, IsAsync=True}"
    ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"
    SelectedIndex="{Binding SelectedIndex}"
    SelectedItem="{Binding SelectBarCode, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
    SelectionMode="Extended"
    Style="{StaticResource ListItemsMain}"
..
```

below is the button code for selecteditem which works fine

```
<Button
   Command="{Binding DataContext.SelectedItemCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ListView}}"
   Content="{Binding SelectedItemContent}" />
```

c#

```
private ICommand mSelectedItemCommand;
public ICommand SelectedItemCommand
    {
        get
        {
            if (mSelectedItemCommand== null)
            {
                mSelectedItemCommand= new DelegateCommand(delegate ()
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(SelectBarCode.BarCodeEntry_ID.ToString());

                });
            }
            return mSelectedItemCommand;
        }
    }
```

and below code is for select index number which does not work

```
<Button
   Command="{Binding DataContext.SelectedIndexCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ListView}}"
   Content="{Binding SelectedIndexContent}" />
```

c#

```
private ICommand mSelectedIndexCommand;
public ICommand SelectedIndexCommand
    {
        get
        {
            if (mSelectedIndexCommand== null)
            {
                mSelectedIndexCommand= new DelegateCommand(delegate ()
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(SelectedIndex.ToString());

                });
            }
            return mSelectedIndexCommand;
        }
    }
```

**Update** below is the complete style for ListViewItem

```
<Style x:Key="FileItemStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="5,5,5,5" />
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0,0,0,0" />
        <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Left" />
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Green" />

        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
                    <Grid
                        Width="195"
                        Height="auto"
                        HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                        VerticalAlignment="Top">
                        <Border>
                            <Border.Background>
                                <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="1,1">
                                    <GradientStop x:Name="GradientStop1" Offset="0.0" Color="#FF2C302C" />
                                    <GradientStop x:Name="GradientStop2" Offset="0.25" Color="#FF3E3C3C" />
                                    <GradientStop x:Name="GradientStop3" Offset="0.75" Color="#FF3E3C3C" />
                                    <GradientStop x:Name="GradientStop4" Offset="1.0" Color="#FF3E3D3C" />
                                </LinearGradientBrush>
                            </Border.Background>

                            <Border.Triggers>
                                <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Border.MouseEnter">
                                    <BeginStoryboard>
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <DoubleAnimation
                                                Storyboard.TargetName="GradientStop1"
                                                Storyboard.TargetProperty="Offset"
                                                From="0.0"
                                                To="1.0"
                                                Duration="0:0:0.25" />
                                            <ColorAnimation
                                                Storyboard.TargetName="GradientStop4"
                                                Storyboard.TargetProperty="Color"
                                                To="DarkGray"
                                                Duration="0:0:0.25" />
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </BeginStoryboard>
                                </EventTrigger>
                                <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Border.MouseLeave">
                                    <BeginStoryboard>
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <DoubleAnimation
                                                Storyboard.TargetName="GradientStop1"
                                                Storyboard.TargetProperty="Offset"
                                                From="1.0"
                                                To="0.0"
                                                Duration="0:0:0.25" />
                                            <ColorAnimation
                                                Storyboard.TargetName="GradientStop4"
                                                Storyboard.TargetProperty="Color"
                                                To="#FF3E3C3C"
                                                Duration="0:0:0.25" />
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </BeginStoryboard>
                                </EventTrigger>



                            </Border.Triggers>
                            <Border.Style>
                                <Style TargetType="Border">
                                    <!--<Setter Property="Background" Value="#FF3E3C3C" />-->
                                    <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
                                    <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
                                    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{x:Null}" />
                                    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1" />
                                    <Setter Property="CornerRadius" Value="15" />
                                    <Style.Triggers>
                                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                                            <Setter Property="Cursor" Value="Hand" />

                                        </Trigger>
                                    </Style.Triggers>
                                </Style>
                            </Border.Style>
                        </Border>
                        <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
                            <ContentPresenter />
                        </StackPanel>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsKeyboardFocusWithin" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="True" />
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>

    </Style>
```

**Update 2:** ObserverableCollection

```
public ObservableCollection<BarCodeModel> BarCode
    {
        get
        {
            mBarCode = mBarCode ?? new ObservableCollection<BarCodeModel>();
            return mBarCode;
        }
    }
```

thin in contructor i assign it to CollViewSourceBarCode

```
CollViewSourceBarCode = new CollectionViewSource();
CollViewSourceBarCode.Source = BarCode;
```

Code for selecteditem

```
public BarCodeModel mSelecBarCode;
    public BarCodeModel SelectBarCode
    {
        get => mSelecBarCode;
        set
        {
            if (value != null)
            {
                mSelecBarCode = value;                    
                OnPropertyChanged("SelectBarCode");
            }
        }
    }
```

code for selectedindex

```
private int mSelectedIndex;
    public int SelectedIndex
    {
        get => mSelectedIndex;
        set
        {
            mSelectedIndex = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("SelectedIndex");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Could you give me a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and share is via github so that I don't have to deal with unnecessaty details.

Comment: Is Button in ListViewItemTemplate, or is it separate from ListView?

Comment: @Rekshino yes it is in  <ListView.ItemTemplate>

Comment: @UsmanAli Does it work with ListView.SelectionMode=Single?

Comment: @Rekshino wow man, i made the SelectionMode="Single" and it worked

Comment: @Rekshino could you please remove your below answer and put <ListView                       
    Grid.Row="1"
    ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource FileItemStyle}"
    ItemsSource="{Binding CollViewSourceBarCode.View, IsAsync=True}"
    ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"
    SelectedIndex="{Binding SelectedIndex}"
    SelectedItem="{Binding SelectBarCode, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
    SelectionMode="Single"
    Style="{StaticResource ListItemsMain}"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the problem was the `SelectionMode`. It should be `Single`.

```
<ListView                       
    Grid.Row="1"
    ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource FileItemStyle}"
    ItemsSource="{Binding CollViewSourceBarCode.View, IsAsync=True}"
    ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"
    SelectedIndex="{Binding SelectedIndex}"
    SelectedItem="{Binding SelectBarCode, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
    SelectionMode="Single"
    Style="{StaticResource ListItemsMain}"
```